# Правила именования полей и свойств

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, а есть ли какие-то правила именования полей и свойств в *C#*?

Например, VS мне автоматом подсказывает, что поля должны именоваться, как `_fieldName`, а свойства как `PropertyName`.

Разве поля и свойства не должны иметь одинаковые правила именования?

Разве не более удобно именовать классовые переменные через `_`? Ведь в таком случае сразу видно, что идет работа с полем или свойством класса.

Comment: [Соглашения о написании кода на C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff926074.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ООП есть такое понятие как инкапсуляция - доступ к полей объекта должен проходить опосредованно, через его методы (в основном имеются ввиду get- set- методы). Свойства в C# - упрощения "гетеров" и "сетеров". Их (свойства) есть смысл объявлять публичными (иначе они бесполезны, разве что object Sv {get; **private set**;})

Очень часто используется следующая конструкция:

```
private object _example; //может быть просто example
public object Example { get {return _example;} set { _example = value; } //value - зарезервированное слово, которое описывает значение, передаваемое при определении (переопределении/переменной); аналогично public void setExample(object val){ _example = val; }
```

Свойства в VS выделяются отдельными иконками и со временем Вы поймете, что такие правила наименований и отделений переменных от свойств куда удобнее и практичнее, чем использование только переменных.

Answer (score 3):

> Разве поля и свойства не должны иметь одинаковые правила именования?

Ни в коем случае, не забывайте что поле класса - это переменная, а свойство это, грубо говоря, функция. Что касается подсказок `VS`, то она намекает вам таким образом, что свойства лучше делать публичными, формируя интерфейс класса, а поля приватными.